# C# Поиск определенной последовательности в byte[] массиве, есть ли стандартный метод?

Tags: c#, массивы, поиск, byte, числовые-последовательности

Есть ли какой-то метод в C# поиска в byte[] массиве определенной последовательности?

*У меня есть файл, который считываю так: `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathExe)`. Мне нужно после считывания найти позицию начала конкретной последовательности из 8 байт (8-ми элементов массива byte[]). Если есть готовое решение укажите пожалуйста.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/byte-to-hex-string (тут есть то что упростит задачу поиска метод byte-to-hex-string, но это не прямой ответ на вопрос)

Comment: возможный дубликат [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/byte-array-pattern-search)

Comment: @Lolidze  спасибо полезно!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всегда есть решение в виде адского Linq-однострочника:

```
byte[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
byte[] b = { 3, 4, 3, 2 };
int? n = Enumerable
    .Range(0, a.Length - b.Length + 1)
    .SkipWhile(x => b.Zip(a.Skip(x), (y, z) => y == z).Any(t => !t))
    .Select(x => (int?)x)
    .FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Вернет индекс первого вхождения массива `b` в `a` или `null` если оно отсутствует.

То же самое в классическом императивном стиле:

```
byte[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
byte[] b = { 3, 4, 3, 2 };
int? n = null;
for (int i = 0; i <= a.Length - b.Length; ++i)
{
    bool f = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; ++j)
    {
        f &= a[i + j] == b[j];
        if (!f) break;
    }
    if (f)
    {
        n = i;
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Comment: Почему-то так зацикливается у меня.

Comment: Нечему тут зацикливаться. Может вам null возвращается?

Comment: Возможно долго ищет, а не зацикливается.

Comment: с вашими массивами проверяю все - ОК.

Comment: с моими массивами - думает уже которую минуту

Comment: Видимо этот метод медленный слишком.

Comment: @SlivinburgskayaDich, сомневаюсь, что существует что-то быстрее этого метода, добавил классический вариант с циклами

Comment: Классический вариант - работает!                                                              А первый вариант - нет( CPU на 50% давит и как будто зациклилась программа

Comment: Неплохо бы ваши тестовые данные увидеть, чтобы протестировать

Comment: `byte[] fileToConvert = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathExe);
            byte[] pattern  = {160, 70, 70, 180, 150, 108, 74, 169, 153, 76, 83, 10, 134, 214, 72, 125 };` любой exe на место `pathExe`. Размер моего exe 1,44 мб

Comment: Ну да, первый метод работает гораздо медленнее, что неудивительно -  перебор каждый раз сначала, квадратичная сложность + накладные расходы. Пользуйтесь вторым, он понятнее, правильнее и быстрее

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну вы, конечно, нашли, куда припаять Linq-однострочник хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, как вы вообще вышли на этот топик три года спустя? :) Ну и да, надо понимать что всегда есть решение в виде адского linq-выражения. Ну и в качестве разминки для мозгов стоит написать его

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а, только сейчас заметил, что это старый. Это не ко мне, а к гражданину, который 20 минут назад дал ответ на решённый 3 года назад вопрос хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, не помню, были ли у меня такие мысли три года назад, но на эту задачу можно смотреть как на поиск подстроки в строке, соответственно лучше всего реализовать КПМ и вот это все. Вероятно это должно быть лучше

Answer (score 0):

Полезняшки от сюда - [линк](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/byte-array-pattern-search)

```
static class ByteArrayRocks
{

    static readonly int[] Empty = new int[0];

    public static int[] Locate(this byte[] self, byte[] candidate)
    {
        if (IsEmptyLocate(self, candidate))
            return Empty;

        var list = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < self.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!IsMatch(self, i, candidate))
                continue;

            list.Add(i);
        }

        return list.Count == 0 ? Empty : list.ToArray();
    }

    static bool IsMatch(byte[] array, int position, byte[] candidate)
    {
        if (candidate.Length > (array.Length - position))
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < candidate.Length; i++)
            if (array[position + i] != candidate[i])
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    static bool IsEmptyLocate(byte[] array, byte[] candidate)
    {
        return array == null
            || candidate == null
            || array.Length == 0
            || candidate.Length == 0
            || candidate.Length > array.Length;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var data = new byte[] { 23, 36, 43, 76, 125, 56, 34, 234, 12, 3, 5, 76, 8, 0, 6, 125, 234, 56, 211, 122, 22, 4, 7, 89, 76, 64, 12, 3, 5, 76, 8, 0, 6, 125 };
        var pattern = new byte[] { 12, 3, 5, 76, 8, 0, 6, 125 };

        foreach (var position in data.Locate(pattern))
            Console.WriteLine(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант для поиска всех совпадений (собирал из нескольких чужих решений):

```
    //Поиск последовательности байтов в массиве
    public List<int> SearchBytePattern(byte[] Source, byte[] Pattern, int Start)
    {
        int SourceLen = Source.Length - Pattern.Length + 1;//Получаем длину исходного массива.
        int j;
        List<int> positions = new List<int>();//Переменная для хранения списка результатов поиска.

        for (int i = Start; i < SourceLen; i++)
        {
            if (Source[i] != Pattern[0]) continue;//Сравниваем первый искомый байт и если он совпадает, то проверяем остальные байты за ним идущие, иначе идем дальше по массиву.
            for (j = Pattern.Length - 1; j >= 1 && Source[i + j] == Pattern[j]; j--);//Сравниваем остальные байты с нашим значением.
            if (j == 0)//Переменная будет равна нулю, если все байты совпали
            {
                positions.Add(i);//Добавляем адрес начала совпадения первого байта в список
                i += Pattern.Length - 1;//Увеличиваем значение переменной на величину искомого, так как мы его уже проверили и это ускоряет поиск.
            }
        }
        return positions;//Отдаем список адресов, которые совпадают с искомым значением.
    }
```